# Illustrator CS6: Where did the debug panel go? Computing area of irregular shapes

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6

I've been looking for ways to compute the area of an irregular shape. I've found this post for tips: http://www.astutegraphics.com/blog/calculating-an-objects-area-in-illustrator/

The keypress combo mentioned - cmd+shift+option+fn+F12 - is not working for me in CS6. Any idea as to what the new keypress combo is? Or how to compute the area of an irregular shape in CS6?

Comment: Good question....

Comment: Argh! I can't believe they dropped that feature without replacing it. It looks like Inkscape has this feature - https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/170757 . You may be able to download and install Inkscape (it's free) and copy over the shapes you want to measure. If it works for you, don't forget to contact Adobe to inform them that to get something done, you had to close the $600 software they sell, and you had to install and open their free, open source rival.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the debug panel (if it's still in the code) isn't hooked up to anything in either version of AI CS6, and it didn't do much of anything in CS5/5.1 either.

There is a [plug-in called Path Area](http://telegraphics.com.au/sw/product/patharea) that works in CS2-CS5.1, but *not* in CS6 (I just tested). If you have CS5 still installed you can run it, otherwise you might check with the telegraphics.com.au folks if anyone might update it. (I see it's referenced on the site you linked in your question.) There have been some pretty massive code changes under the hood in CS6, so 3rd Party "casual" plug-ins like this are likely casualties of that process.

James Talmage ("JET" on the Adobe Forums) had a great script that would do this, but I don't have it and his site is clearly in some kind of rebuild or state of neglect. Links to it that used to work no longer do.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it has been removed from CS6 entirely. (I asked the dev team). They may bring it back later and are evaluating it's uses. Until then, I think Alan has things covered.

Answer (score 1):

I sent a private msg to James Talmage on the Adobe Forums and will report back if/when he gets back to me.

As for the Path Area plugin, I had already tested it before this question and, indeed, it doesn't work in CS6. I haven't found any way to contact the telegraphics.com.au team on their website.

It seems for now there's no real way to compute areas other than divide irregular shapes into regular ones and add their respective areas together then...

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this will help, since this is a pretty old post, but there are scripts written to find the area of a shape in Illy:

http://www.illustrationetc.com/AIbuds/JET_GetInfoScripts.zip

super easy to use

Answer (score -1):

Are you on a Mac? If so, the key combo doesn't work by default. You need to go into System Preferences/Keyboard and check the box that says "Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys". Once you do that, the key combo Cmd+Shift+Option+F12 does indeed bring up the debug panel in Illustrator CS6 (15.1.0)

Comment: CS6 is version 16.1 at the moment. And the panel was removed. The Illustrator Development team confirmed it simply does not exist in Illustrator 16. No key combo or OS altering on the Mac will bring it back for Illustrator CS6. Your suggestion is valid for Illustrator CS5 (v15) however.